# AdminLTE 3 fixed element when scrolling down

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, adminlte

I want the elements of the left (red box) to be fixed so when the page scrolls it stays at the top of the page.
I tried with the property fixed and sticky but they don't work.

The preview

beginning:
[image]

after scroll:
[image]

this is the page https://adminlte.io/themes/dev/AdminLTE/pages/mailbox/read-mail.html

Comment: hope this below answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There's already so many very good examples on [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_sidebar.asp) for `Fixed Sidebar`

and here mine using `Bootstrap 4`, `CSS` and plain `Javascript`

```js
var sideNavBarWidth = document.getElementsByClassName('side-navbar');
var innerNavBar = document.getElementsByClassName('inner-navbar');
// Giving a 1rem space from both side
innerNavBar["0"].style.minWidth = (sideNavBarWidth["0"].offsetWidth - (32)) + 'px';
```

```css
.list-group-item {
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid bg-light">
 <div class="col-12">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-3 border border-dark px-0 py-4 side-navbar">
    <div class="position-fixed inner-navbar mx-3">
     <ol class="list-group">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item my-1">Chapter 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item my-1">Chapter 2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item my-1">Chapter 3</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item my-1">Chapter 4</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item my-1">Chapter 5</a>
     </ol>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-9 border border-dark px-4 py-4">
    <div class="row mb-3 px-4 jumbotron-fluid">
     <h1>Chapter 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-3 px-4 text-justify">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
     labore et dolore magna
     aliqua. Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus nulla at volutpat. Interdum varius sit
     amet mattis vulputate
     enim nulla aliquet. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Blandit aliquam etiam erat velit
     scelerisque in dictum. Sit amet
     massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis. Non arcu risus quis varius. Eget nulla facilisi
     etiam dignissim diam quis.
     Quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et. Nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis.
     Eget duis at tellus at.
     Aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant. Suscipit tellus
     mauris a diam maecenas
     sed enim. Diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque. Orci porta non
     pulvinar neque laoreet
     suspendisse interdum. Sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras. Pulvinar pellentesque
     habitant morbi tristique
     senectus et. Aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar.
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-3 px-4 text-justify">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
     labore et dolore magna
     aliqua. Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus nulla at volutpat. Interdum varius sit
     amet mattis vulputate
     enim nulla aliquet. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Blandit aliquam etiam erat velit
     scelerisque in dictum. Sit amet
     massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis. Non arcu risus quis varius. Eget nulla facilisi
     etiam dignissim diam quis.
     Quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et. Nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis.
     Eget duis at tellus at.
     Aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant. Suscipit tellus
     mauris a diam maecenas
     sed enim. Diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque. Orci porta non
     pulvinar neque laoreet
     suspendisse interdum. Sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras. Pulvinar pellentesque
     habitant morbi tristique
     senectus et. Aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar.
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-3 px-4 text-justify">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
     labore et dolore magna
     aliqua. Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus nulla at volutpat. Interdum varius sit
     amet mattis vulputate
     enim nulla aliquet. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Blandit aliquam etiam erat velit
     scelerisque in dictum. Sit amet
     massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis. Non arcu risus quis varius. Eget nulla facilisi
     etiam dignissim diam quis.
     Quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et. Nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis.
     Eget duis at tellus at.
     Aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant. Suscipit tellus
     mauris a diam maecenas
     sed enim. Diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque. Orci porta non
     pulvinar neque laoreet
     suspendisse interdum. Sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras. Pulvinar pellentesque
     habitant morbi tristique
     senectus et. Aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar.
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-3 px-4 text-justify">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
     labore et dolore magna
     aliqua. Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus nulla at volutpat. Interdum varius sit
     amet mattis vulputate
     enim nulla aliquet. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Blandit aliquam etiam erat velit
     scelerisque in dictum. Sit amet
     massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis. Non arcu risus quis varius. Eget nulla facilisi
     etiam dignissim diam quis.
     Quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et. Nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis.
     Eget duis at tellus at.
     Aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant. Suscipit tellus
     mauris a diam maecenas
     sed enim. Diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque. Orci porta non
     pulvinar neque laoreet
     suspendisse interdum. Sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras. Pulvinar pellentesque
     habitant morbi tristique
     senectus et. Aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar.
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-3 px-4 text-justify">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
     labore et dolore magna
     aliqua. Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus nulla at volutpat. Interdum varius sit
     amet mattis vulputate
     enim nulla aliquet. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Blandit aliquam etiam erat velit
     scelerisque in dictum. Sit amet
     massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis. Non arcu risus quis varius. Eget nulla facilisi
     etiam dignissim diam quis.
     Quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et. Nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis.
     Eget duis at tellus at.
     Aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant. Suscipit tellus
     mauris a diam maecenas
     sed enim. Diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque. Orci porta non
     pulvinar neque laoreet
     suspendisse interdum. Sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras. Pulvinar pellentesque
     habitant morbi tristique
     senectus et. Aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar.
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-3 px-4 text-justify">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
     labore et dolore magna
     aliqua. Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus nulla at volutpat. Interdum varius sit
     amet mattis vulputate
     enim nulla aliquet. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Blandit aliquam etiam erat velit
     scelerisque in dictum. Sit amet
     massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis. Non arcu risus quis varius. Eget nulla facilisi
     etiam dignissim diam quis.
     Quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et. Nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis.
     Eget duis at tellus at.
     Aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant. Suscipit tellus
     mauris a diam maecenas
     sed enim. Diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque. Orci porta non
     pulvinar neque laoreet
     suspendisse interdum. Sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras. Pulvinar pellentesque
     habitant morbi tristique
     senectus et. Aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar.
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-3 px-4 text-justify">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
     labore et dolore magna
     aliqua. Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus nulla at volutpat. Interdum varius sit
     amet mattis vulputate
     enim nulla aliquet. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Blandit aliquam etiam erat velit
     scelerisque in dictum. Sit amet
     massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis. Non arcu risus quis varius. Eget nulla facilisi
     etiam dignissim diam quis.
     Quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et. Nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis.
     Eget duis at tellus at.
     Aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant. Suscipit tellus
     mauris a diam maecenas
     sed enim. Diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque. Orci porta non
     pulvinar neque laoreet
     suspendisse interdum. Sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras. Pulvinar pellentesque
     habitant morbi tristique
     senectus et. Aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar.
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-3 px-4 text-justify">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
     labore et dolore magna
     aliqua. Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus nulla at volutpat. Interdum varius sit
     amet mattis vulputate
     enim nulla aliquet. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Blandit aliquam etiam erat velit
     scelerisque in dictum. Sit amet
     massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis. Non arcu risus quis varius. Eget nulla facilisi
     etiam dignissim diam quis.
     Quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et. Nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis.
     Eget duis at tellus at.
     Aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant. Suscipit tellus
     mauris a diam maecenas
     sed enim. Diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque. Orci porta non
     pulvinar neque laoreet
     suspendisse interdum. Sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras. Pulvinar pellentesque
     habitant morbi tristique
     senectus et. Aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar.
    </div>

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Hope, this would help your scenario.

Comment: Thanks. I think I didn't define well my problem. I tried to modify the css with position: fixed, but when scrolling on the page, the elements on the left are not positioned at the top of the page because they continue to respect the space where the navbar and the Content Header were positioned (Page header) of the template. I have tried with position: sticky but without success.
I modified the question to try to better explain the problem.